# C/C++ Interface with HID - USB Device

Tags: c, interface, communication, joystick

I have a gamepad and i want to use the buttons on the joystick to interact with my program. I have been searching for a while now for any solutions and i cant find any. I have the device id and the vendor id are there any good example as to how i can accomplish this?

Comment: What platform are you developing on/for?

Comment: i dont think hes a c programmer either

Comment: I am developing for the windows platform

Comment: nobody goes from VB to C.  at least you're the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [libusb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/), a C library for accessing USB devices.  It is available on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The [SDL Library](http://www.libsdl.org/) can access joysticks and controller.

Here's some documentation about this topic:

- [Joystick Support](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/CategoryJoystick)
- [GameController and Joystick Mapping](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/CategoryGameController)